# Get response from PostAsJsonAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have this line of code

```
var response = new HttpClient().PostAsJsonAsync(posturi, model).Result;
```

The Called WebAPI controller returns a bool to make sure the object was saved, but how do I return that bool response?

Comment: Use the debugger to explore the response object. Also get Fiddler to see what is being posted & received. Also use await - rather than .Response if you want to use this in an Async way.

Comment: Visitors: PostAsJsonAsync is not in the main library in newer .net, though you can find it.  My research points to generating the Json yourself and calling PostAsync.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Continue to get from content:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(posturi, model).Result;
bool returnValue = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<bool>().Result;
```

But, this is really naive approach for quick way to get result. `PostAsJsonAsync` and `ReadAsAsync` is not designed to do like this, they are designed to support `async await` programming, so your code should be:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(posturi, model);
bool returnValue = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<bool>();
```

Also, instead of using a flag to check whether an object is saved or not, you should make use of HTTP codes by returning `200 OK` to determine that saving is successfully.

Comment: Lee, for this particular situation there is a very specific why I'm not in this instance

Comment: Why `.Result` and blocking instead of `await`?

Answer (score 42):

The accepted answer is technically correct but blocks the current thread on calls to `.Result`. If you are using .NET 4.5 or higher, you should avoid that in almost all situations. Instead, use the equivalent asynchronous (non-blocking) version:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(posturi, model);
bool returnValue = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<bool>();
```

Note that the method containing the above code needs to be marked `async`, and should itself be `await`ed.

Answer (score 13):

Since its an Async operation don't immediately do `.Result` as its wrong

Instead you need to do it async by doing this:

```
    var httpClient = new HttpClient()

    var task = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(posturi, model)
                         .ContinueWith( x => x.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<bool>().Result);

    // 1. GETTING RESPONSE - NOT ASYNC WAY
    task.Wait(); //THIS WILL HOLD THE THREAD AND IT WON'T BE ASYNC ANYMORE!
    bool response = task.Result

    // 2. GETTING RESPONSE - TASK ASYNC WAY (usually used in < .NET 4.5 
    task.ContinueWith( x => {
                              bool response = x.Result
                          });

    // 3. GETTING RESPONSE - TASK ASYNC WAY (usually used in >= .NET 4.5 
    bool response = await task;
```

NOTE: I just wrote them in here, so I didnt actually test them but more or less that's what you want.

I hope it helps!

Comment: I'd recommend not wrapping httpClient in a using statement - https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Answer (score 3):

I used HttpStatusCode to check the result.

```
    public HttpStatusCode PostStaffPositions(Foo foo)
    {
        string uri = myapiuri;

        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, foo).Result;
            return response.StatusCode;
        }
    }
```

And then in Controller check it like this:

```
   HttpStatusCode update = staffrest.PostStaffPositions(foo);
            if (update == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
               //Update Succeed
            }
            else
            {
                //Update Failed
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you call the generic version, it should give you back the bool:

```
var response = new HttpClient().PostAsJsonAsync<bool>(posturi, model).Result;
```

At least according to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944521%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

Comment: I think <T> affects the request, not the response.

Comment: Be very careful of using .Result on async. Easiest way to get threading deadlocks in ASP and UI applications.

Answer (score 1):

It's July 2021 and I'm using .net 5 (namely the .net core 5).

I did not see any generic methods above in System.Net.Http. Now the code looks like this (tested):

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44330/api/Book/Add");
    var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(client.BaseAddress,
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(_teamSummaries));
    MessageBox.Show(@"Result is " + JsonSerializer.Serialize(response));
    var returnValue = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    MessageBox.Show(@"Return value is " + returnValue.Result);
}
```

There are also ReadAsStringAsync, ReadAsByteArrayAsync, ReadAsStream, ReadFromJsonAsync, `ReadFromJsonAsync<T>` (this method returns `Task<T>`).

But from the text meaning "ReadFromJsonAsync", I think the T is not the bool mentioned above, but a class that contains the bool member. If you want to return something like book, give it a try.

On the other hands, since code on the server looks like this(.net 5):

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Add")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Book>>> Add(string value)
{
    var all = await _dbCollection.FindAsync(Builders<Book>.Filter.Empty);
    return Ok("Everything is ok.");
}
```

So, if we want to return true by bool, we should return Ok(...). If we want to return false by bool, we should return something else. There are more than 20 other types of results, which contains much more information rather than just "false".