# Accessing Value Returned from WebApi Post Method in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-web-api

I have `webapi` post method which returns an integer values between 1 and 5 based on certain criteria when a call is made from a `WPF` application. The `api` is working well and returns status 200 when called.

Issue: I want to access the integer value returned in the response.

webapi:

```
 [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public int ValidateLicence(dto_User user)
        {
                var result = _repository.ValidateLicence(user);
            return result;

        }
```

reponse (wpf):

```
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/User/ValidateLicence/", licence);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get response from PostAsJsonAsync](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205389/get-response-from-postasjsonasync)

Comment: Not helpful @ChrisBint. I need someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Run a communications trace and tell us what is  being returned.  What do you get in the response? Nothing?

Comment: I have resolved it by changing the api `post` method to a `get` method and `PostAsJsonAsync` to `GetAsync`.